# Email forwarding available in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

My requirement of user sign-in disabled and receives an email on this user to forwarding to another user using Microsoft graph API.

I found the user account enable-disable using user update API. But, could not found email forwarding.

It is possible in Microsoft graph API?

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at this documentation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I need a permanent email forwarding. When a disabled user receives the email that email forward to another user.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I haven't managed to find a solution using Graph yet and I'm not sure SMTP forwarding can be configured using it. As a workaround I've developed my application to wrap Exchange Online PowerShell to apply and clear forwards on mailboxes as required. This works, though compared to the performance of Graph its very slow :(

Comment: This is the first option in google, but it is not the right option. It allows you to forward a single email. Which is no good here.